# How to debug potential CPU/RAM errors in Bash script on Linux

Tags: bash, shell, hardware, cpu

I have a relatively simple bash script that reads from a set of static input files, stores the input in bash variables and then does a bunch of processing over said input by calling out to external scripts (e.g. written in Python, Go, other bash scripts etc.) and using the intermediate results.

Lately I have been experiencing an intermittent problem where a single character seems to be getting altered somewhere during the processing which then causes subsequent errors.  Specifically, a lot of the processing I'm doing involves slicing up a list of comma-separated records, and one of the values on each line is a unix timestamp, e.g. `1354245000`.

What seems to be happening is that occasionally one of these values will get altered slightly, so I end up with a timestamp like `13542458=2` or `13542458>2` or `13542458;2` coming out of one of the intermediate scripts.  This then subsequently gets fed into another script, which throws an exception when it tries to parse the value to an integer.

In the title of this question, I've suggested that this might be a potential CPU/RAM error.  I know the general folly in thinking errors are caused by low level things like hardware/compilers etcetera, but the nature of this particular error makes me think it may be possible, for the following reasons:

1. The input files are the same on each invocation of the script, and the script only fails on some invocations.
2. I cannot think of any sources of randomness in the source code prior to where the script is breaking.  It's basically just slicing and dicing csv input.
3. I cannot think of any sources of concurrency in the source code -- even the Go scripts aren't actually written to run anything concurrently.
4. This problem has only arisen in the last week or so.  Prior to this time, this error would never occur.
5. While I haven't documented every erroneous character, they seem to often be quite close in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to numeric values (`=`, `>`, `;` etc).  That said, I guess the Hamming distance between two characters quite far apart can be small also with changes to a high order bit.
6. The script often breaks at a different stage on different runs.  i.e. I have a number of separate Python scripts, and sometimes it'll make it past one script and then the error will be induced in another.  Other times it'll be induced on an earlier script.

What I'd like to know is, *is there any methodical way to either confirm or rule out a hardware error for this problem*?  Or if it is a hardware problem, is it possibly undetectable by the operating system?

A bit of further info on the machine:

- Linux 64-bit, Ubuntu 12.04
- Intel i7 processor
- 16GB DDR3 RAM

I'm hoping someone can either point me to a reliable way to verify whether the hardware is to blame or otherwise a sound reason as to what else might be the cause.

Comment: The first thing to do is standard software debugging. For example, have you identified which script is causing the problem?

Comment: Have you made updates before that? Esp. the kernel.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Just added a sixth point to clarify - it fails on different scripts on different invocations.

Comment: @konsolebox in the general area of the script that is failing (around the beginning), I don't believe I made any updates in quite a while and this is only a new error.

Comment: Whilst it's possible this is a hardware problem, this would likely be causing you other problems too (e.g. system crashes/instability). I would focus on constructing the smallest possible test case (both data and code), otherwise this is all just speculation :(

Comment: Since you run Ubuntu, there should be a "Memory Test" boot option, have you tried that?

Comment: It could also be possible that the tool you use is somewhat now getting an unusual data. Perhaps trying a new version could fix it.

Comment: Try popping a couple of different RAM sticks in - they are hardly expensive! Not sure about Ubuntu, but I know Solaris makes entries in syslog on detecting RAM parity errors...

Comment: Update: @ammoQ and Mark Setchell I think the RAM is indeed the problem.  I'm running it through Memtest as we speak and there's a bunch of errors clustered around a certain area of memory.  I'll remove the problem RAM later and re-try.  ammoQ if you wanted to post Mem Test as an answer I'll accept it for now, otherwise I'll post it myself if you don't get round to it.  Cheers.

Comment: Ok, posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try booting into `Memtest` to check your memory.

Answer (score 1):

While it is highly unlikely that it will be hardware, if you have exhausted you standard software debug as suggested by @OliCharlesworth, here is an outline of hardware error investigation:

```
(1) check your log area for any `MCE` logs (machine check exceptions). 
    If you find any in either your log area (syslog) or sometimes in
    the present working dir or /dir -- you have a hardware failure.

(2) check your log area for disk errors. e.g: 
    smartd[3963]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], 34 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors

(3) check your drive integrity, e.g.: (as root) # `smartctl -a /dev/sda` if any abnormality, run:
    smartctl -t short /dev/sda (change drive as required)

(4)  download/install/boot to [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm)
     (run the complete test)
```

If your cpu/motherboard has thrown no mce's, you have no disk error, your drive tests OK with smartctl and you have no memory errors with memtest86, then recheck the software debugging. While additional hardware errors can still be present (bad capacitors, etc..) the likelihood at this point is software. Good luck.